# Computer crashed while updating to new Ubuntu 20.04 release

Tags: 20.04, updates, restart

I have been using Ubuntu for quite some time, I have decided to update to the new release.
While it was updating (loading the new packages) it just logged me out from my session and I was asked to log in again. When trying to log in again I got the message “oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can’t recover. Please log out and try again”. Logging in again I got the same message so I tried to restart my laptop and got this message “oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can’t recover. Please contact a system administrator.”

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Before rebooting

```
ctrl-alt-F2 
login
```

and then:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove
```

solved the problem for me, so that I could reboot.
But I have still network problems.

Comment: That a look into journalctl. Can you find any errors during upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps no more place. After an update a lot of package are downloaded and your / is full and system can't not create tmp file
Try to clean package downloaded with command sudo apt-get clean.
CTRL+F1 for switching to a console.

Answer (score 0):

Your system might be properly broken and require a fresh installation. We upgraded many machines (>30) using this procedure recently and only one VM experienced problems.

As user206* above says, try to log in to a console or boot to a console with Ctrl + F1

```
# is the hard disk 100 % full ?
df -h
# try to resume the upgrade
sudo apt upgrade 
# perhaps try this
sudo apt upgrade -f
```

Try to follow any hints the package manager gives you to try to restore your system (eg dpkg -i commands)